# How to set all coefficients to one in model?

Tags: r, model, regression

To fix certain coefficient in regression to one we can use `offset` function.

I want to set all coefficients to 1.

Let's take this example:

```
set.seed(42)
y <- rnorm(100)
df <- data.frame("Uni" = runif(100), "Exp" = rexp(100), "Wei" = rweibull(100, 1))
lm(y~ offset(2*get("Uni")) + Exp + Wei, data = df)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ offset(Uni) + offset(Exp) + offset(Wei), data = df)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)  
     -2.712
```

This code works, however what if I have huge amount of data e.g. 800 variables and I want to do for all of them ? Writing all their names would be not so efficient. Is there any solution which allows us to do it more tricky ?

Comment: you can define the formula within a loop

Comment: Why use regression? You can just Calculate a sum.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found one solution if we do it this way:

```
set.seed(42)
# Assign everything to one data frame 
df <- data.frame("Dep" = rnorm(100), "Uni" = runif(100),
                 "Exp" = rexp(100), "Wei" = rweibull(100, 1))
varnames <- names(df)[-1]
# Create formula for the sake of model creation
form <- paste0("offset","(",varnames, ")",collapse = "+")
form <- as.formula(paste0(names(df)[1], "~", form))
lm(form, data = df)
```

Answer (score 0):

**1) terms/update** The following one-liner will produce the indicated formula.

```
update(formula(terms(y ~ ., data = df)), ~ offset(.))
## y ~ offset(Uni + Exp + Wei)
```

**2) reformulate/sprintf** another approach is:

```
reformulate(sprintf("offset(%s)", names(df)), "y")
## y ~ offset(Dep) + offset(Uni) + offset(Exp) + offset(Wei)
```

**3) rowSums** Another approach is to simply sum each row:

```
lm(y ~ offset(rowSums(df)))
```

**4) lm.fit** We could use lm.fit in which case we don't need a formula:

```
lm.fit(cbind(y^0), y, offset = rowSums(df))
```

**5) mean** If you only need the coefficient then it is just:

```
mean(y - rowSums(df))
```